# AWS Fargate deploy: "Invalid action configuration The AWS ECS container ***** does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using terraform to provision the resources required.

I have a terraform codepipeline `resource` and the `Production` `stage` reads the `imagedefinitions.json` file to know which images to deploy:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline" {
  stage {
    name = "Build"
    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      version          = "1"
      input_artifacts  = ["source"]
      output_artifacts = ["imagedefinitions"]
      configuration {
        ProjectName = "${var.project_prefix}-codebuild"
      }
    }
  }
 stage {
    name = "Production"
    action {
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "ECS"
      input_artifacts = ["imagedefinitions"]
      version         = "1"
      configuration {
        ClusterName = "${var.ecs_cluster_name}"
        ServiceName = "${var.ecs_service_name}"
        FileName    = "imagedefinitions.json"
      }
    }
  }
```

The `imagedefinitions.json` file is built during the build phase, from `buildspec.yml`:

```
build:
  commands:
    - echo Build started on 'date'
    - echo Building the Docker image...
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
post_build:
  commands:
    - echo Build completed on 'date'
    - echo Pushing the Docker images...
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    - echo Writing image definitions file...
    - printf '[{"name":"docker-image-name","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
```

I am not sure what the name of the image should be in this line:

> - printf '[{"name":"docker-image-name","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json

The error I get repeats the "name" value from this line:

> "Invalid action configuration The AWS ECS container docker-image-name does not exist"

What is the name I should have in here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Continuous Deployment with AWS CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html) tutorial. From [Prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html#ecs-cd-prereqs), you should have a task definition, and a service that uses the task definition.

When the **ECS Deploy** step in the CodePipeline runs, it looks up the task definition for the service you specify, creates a new task definition where it updates the container with the same `name` as the one in your `imagedefinition.json` file.

So from your example, I would expect the Task Definition associated with the ECS Service your pipeline is updating to have a container with the name `docker-image-name`.

Comment: thanks! I was reading a tutorial that had taken some of that code, but not explained it. It was much better reading the original. I had a different `name` in the `task_definition.json` than the `name` I was writing to the `imagedefinitions.json` file.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I had named my container "app" in the TaskDefinition, but when I was creating the imagedefinition,json file from CodeBuild, it was using the container name "api" as I coped that code over from another project. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You have created an ERC repo and you have up uploaded an image to it?
This might help, I saw this which looks kinda similiar to a part of what you are trying to achieve:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-catsndogs-workshop/blob/master/Lab-6-Artifacts/dogs/buildspec.yml